# How to return an async map function in the correct order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have this function right here:

```js
const uploadedFiles: string[] = [];
await Promise.all(
   selectedImageUrls.map(async (selectedUrl) => {
       const fileName = selectedUrl.startsWith("data:image/png")
          ? `${id}-${Date.now()}.png`
          : `${id}-${getFileNameFromUrl(selectedUrl)}`;
       const fileData = await fetch(selectedUrl).then((x) => x.arrayBuffer());
       const newUrl = await uploadInvoiceFile(userId, fileName, fileData);
       uploadedFiles.push(newUrl);
   })
);
```

So basically I have an array called `selectedImageUrls` and I map through this array to execute some async functions so I put this map inside of a `Promise.all()` and on the last line, you can see that in every map, I push the result of the async functions into an array called `uploadedFiles`, however, this result is not in the same order as the original array (`selectedImageUrls`). How can I modify this code so that the order will be exactly the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` will return requests in the same order you created the map.  But the order things get completed could be out of order.

So all you need to do is get the results from `Promise.all`.
eg..

```
const uploadedFiles = await Promise.all(
   selectedImageUrls.map(async (selectedUrl) => {
       const fileName = selectedUrl.startsWith("data:image/png")
          ? `${id}-${Date.now()}.png`
          : `${id}-${getFileNameFromUrl(selectedUrl)}`;
       const fileData = await fetch(selectedUrl).then((x) => x.arrayBuffer());
       const newUrl = await uploadInvoiceFile(userId, fileName, fileData);
       return newUrl;
   })
);
```

Ps.  seen as your using Typescript, the nice thing is that `uploadedFiles` will implicitly be of type `string[]` too, assuming `newUrl` is a string of course..

Also a little tip, if last thing you do inside an `async` function is return a promise, you can skip the temporary variable and `await`.

eg.

```
const newUrl = await uploadInvoiceFile(userId, fileName, fileData);
return newUrl;
```

Can be simplified to ->

```
return uploadInvoiceFile(userId, fileName, fileData);
```

Answer (score 1):

> in every map, I push the result of the async functions into an array called `uploadedFiles`

Just don't do that. `Promise.all` will already create an array with all the promise results, use that:

```
const uploadedFiles: string[] = await Promise.all(
    selectedImageUrls.map(async selectedUrl => {
        const fileName = selectedUrl.startsWith("data:image/png")
          ? `${id}-${Date.now()}.png`
          : `${id}-${getFileNameFromUrl(selectedUrl)}`;
        const x = await fetch(selectedUrl)
        const fileData = await x.arrayBuffer();
        return uploadInvoiceFile(userId, fileName, fileData);
//      ^^^^^^
    })
);
```